# CSS auto height and sticky footer

Tags: layout, sticky-footer, css

I'm trying to wrap my head around CSS positioning guidelines.  I'm trying to figure out how to make a sticky footer but have it stop being sticky when the main content area can no longer be condensed.  An example of what I'm talking about can be found here http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/.  Can someone explain to me why the footer stops being sticky and particularly what CSS properties cause this to occur?  For me, as I look at the CSS it looks like the footer should just stay sticky to the bottom of the browser window always, but this isn't the case here.  Why?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this one a try. 
http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/ (link no longer valid)

It is similar to Ryan's one but, from memory, I think I've had better luck with this  (although both are very similar).

Comment: please provide some code as the site you have linked is down.

Comment: LOL - Well it WAS 6 and a half years ago! Are you that surprised the link is no longer valid?  And just like everything in frontend development, its been superseded by new technologies such as Flexbox and CSS grid. So there's no point in reposting that old code!

Comment: yea good point, but atleast that old code logic could have gave a hint even though its outdated/no longer valid. Just from community point it makes more sense to have real code in answer rather then links. @swisstony make an edit so I can upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the footer outside of the wrapper and give some `height` for footer and margin-top should `-(footer-height)px`

```
<div id="wrapper">
  ---
 ------
</div>
<div id="footer">
</div>

# wrapper {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
#footer {
width:100%;
height:25px;
margin:-25px 0px 0px 0px;
background:#ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a brief summary of a layout I use fairly consistently as a basis for projects that require a sticky footer. Not sure where I initially got all the code from but it was pieced together over quite a while.

http://jsfiddle.net/biznuge/thbuf/8/

You should be able to see from the fiddle that you require a '#container' element which will wrap the whole of the page. this gives you 100% height (note the hacks for ie present in the css), and allows and child elements of this 'container' element to derive a height, or position relative to it.

Pitfalls of this method are:

- You need to provide some padding/margin at the bottom of the '#main'
  element so that the footer is displaced further than it naturally
  would, so need to know at least a broad range of what your footer
  height should be.
- IE doesn't seem (<=IE8 not tested 9) to recognize    browser resize
  events if you only resize the bottom edge of the    browser, so in
  that particular case the stickiness would fail, until    a horizontal
  resize was also presented as an event.
- if you want a    fixed width to the layout you should place this
  constraint not on the    '#container' element, but on the '#page'
  element, and perhaps    introduce extra elements beneath '#footer' to
  provide any width    constraints there.

Good Luck!